Screen sharing high CPU usage when using mouse / keyboard
I'm connecting into an M1 macbook (Sonoma) from a 2019 iMac (Sonoma, 64GB, i9, Radeon 570x 4GB) using Apple Screen Sharing.
Especially when viewing Chrome / Electron based applications, the iMac's fans start spinning at full rev, and I notice 100% or more CPU usage by the Screen sharing app (not globally as shown on the Activity Monitor graph). I've noticed that it happens when there is mouse or keyboard activity; as soon as I switch out of the Screen Sharing app on the iMac, the CPU usage gets down to normal, even when I keep the Screen Sharing window visible, with all the macbook's UI updates going on.
Sure, it's summer, the 2019 iMac isn't a youngster or a graphics dragon, but:

if I connect into the very same M1 from my 2015 iMac (Mojave), I don't have this problem, the fans spin up now and then, but nothing noticeable;
it's not Sonoma specific, because I don't have problems connecting from my M2 macbook (Sonoma, ARD classic mode, the advanced is too buggy) either (but it can be Intel-Sonoma specific);
it really is bound to mouse / keyboard activity, and it really depends on the app running on the M1, Chrome + Electron apps being the worst offenders.

My solution so far has been to throw cpulimit with a 75% limit at Screen Sharing. It solves the fan noise, but Screen Sharing starts stuttering a lot with some Electron apps (not all). Then I stop using the mouse or keyboard, and it gets back to running smoothly.
Does anyone have any pointers?

The typical controls for managing this are several:

Reduce the bit depth on the source Mac
Reduce the resolution on the source Mac
Lower the refresh rate on the source Mac
Connect an HDMI dongle (a.k.a ghost display) to engage GPU rendering on the source Mac.
Reduce virtual displays
Reduce physically connected displays
Eliminate DisplayLink if you installed it on the source Mac.
Reduce the number of finder previews that are visible and dock previews
Use a basic desktop background
Reduce motion on the source Mac in Accessibility

At that point, you will have optimized the GPU side of things.
Now reduce other CPU tasks till you are 50 to 35% idle on the CPU side overall. I wouldn’t try to throttle the screen sharing process, but instead free it up to do its job without buffering or lag. It’s the symptom of overload, not the cause. Perhaps something like App Tamer could help once you exhaust the above suggestions?
